# What's with the shark in the pool?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, the-matador

During [*The Matador*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0365485/), at the morning after his bar talk with Danny, we see Julian walk through the hotel lobby in swimming wear and boots and jump right into the pool with his beer can still in his hand. Then under the water he suddenly sees a friggin' shark swimming around. Now seeing that there was unlikely to be a real shark in the hotel pool, this might just have been a way to show his drunk mind. But this scene somehow seemed totally out of place (and immediately after that it cuts to Danny saying farewell to his business partner and being approached by Julian for an apology).

So I wonder **if there was anything more to this weird shark scene** and if it relates in any way to the rest of the story, Julian's character or the scenes immediately surrounding it.

Comment: Just another sign that he's coming apart at the seams, IMO.